# Which is the suitable tool to automate test cases for an hybrid application done with angular JS in tablet

Tags: angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor, appium

For a given tablet application done with AngularJS what are the best practices and tools to automate my test cases?

- Protractor with Selenium and Jasmin
- Can i combine Appium with Protractor the idea comes to me from that question:  [Original idea source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31937551/can-you-use-protractor-and-appium-together-to-test-hybrid-apps)

Answer (score 0):

If your application is written in accessibility standards it's easy to automate using any object based testing framework like appium

Comment: In my case, what shall i use : 
-Appium ?
-Selenium with protractor ?
Is there a difference between them to automate test cases?